# How can I make my class name italic and bold? [TikZ-UML]

Tags: bold, italic, tikz-uml

I am trying to make an abstract class name italic and bold at the same time but with the argument "type=abstract" I just get italic style but not bold.

Is there any way that it will get bold too? 
It doesn't look really nice because all other classes are bold.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,twoside]{report}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tikz-uml}

\begin{document} 
\begin{tikzpicture} 
\umlclass[type=abstract]{\textbf{AbstractClass}}{}{}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Package needed to compile from here: http://perso.ensta-paristech.fr/~kielbasi/tikzuml/

Comment: Welcome to [TeX.SX](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)! Please help us (and also you) and add a minimal working example ([MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that)), that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: There is a line `\def\tikzumlClassName{{\it \tikzumlClassNameOld}}` inside the `sty` file which could be changed to something like `\def\tikzumlClassName{\textbf{\emph{\tikzumlClassNameOld}}}`, but this may be not the best way to deal with this.

Comment: Thank you very much for your response! I will try this now.

Comment: I have changed the line   `\ifthenelse{\equal{\tikzumlAssocClassTypeTmp}{abstract}}{%
    \let\tikzumlAssocClassNameOld\tikzumlAssocClassName%
    \def\tikzumlAssocClassName{{\textbf{\emph{\tikzumlAssocClassNameOld}}}}%` now and were running`texhash ~/texmf` but it's still just italic not bold.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works by changing line 460 (Version 29 March 2016) in tikz-uml.sty file from

```
\ifthenelse{\equal{\tikzumlClassTypeTmp}{abstract}}{%
\let\tikzumlClassNameOld\tikzumlClassName%
\def\tikzumlClassName{{\it \tikzumlClassNameOld}}%
```

To

```
\ifthenelse{\equal{\tikzumlClassTypeTmp}{abstract}}{%
\let\tikzumlClassNameOld\tikzumlClassName%
\def\tikzumlClassName{{\textbf{\emph{\tikzumlClassNameOld}}}}%
```

Thanks to @epR8GaYuh for pointing out.